# group by year month in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
 customer      Date      location

     1         25Jan2018     texas

     2         15Jan2018     texas

     3         12Feb2018     Boston

     4         19Mar2017     Boston.
```

I am trying to find out count of customers group by yearmon of Date column.Date column is of text data type

eg: In jan2018 ,the count is 2

Comment: What about 1 digit days, like January 1:st, are these stored as 01Jan2019, or 1Jan2019?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like the following:

```
SELECT
  date_part('year', formattedDate) as Year
 ,date_part('month', formattedDate) as Month
 ,count(*) as CustomerCountByYearMonth
FROM
 (SELECT to_date(Date,'DDMonYYYY') as formattedDate from <table>) as tbl1
GROUP BY
  date_part('year', formattedDate)
 ,date_part('month', formattedDate)
```

Any additional formatting for dates could be done on the inner query that will allow for adjustments in case some single digit days need to be padded or a month has four letters instead of three etc.

By converting to date type, you can properly order by date type and not alphabetical etc.

Optionally:

```
SELECT
  Year
 ,Month
 ,count(*) as CustomerCountByYearMonth
FROM
 (SELECT
   date_part('year', to_date(Date,'DDMonYYYY')) as Year
  ,date_part('month', to_date(Date,'DDMonYYYY')) as Month
 FROM <table>) as tbl1
GROUP BY
  Year
 ,Month
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't store dates in a text column...

```
select substring(Date, length(Date)-6), count(*)
from tablename
group by substring(Date, length(Date)-6)
```

Comment: Question is about count for each month of each year present in the table. Thus group by is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I thought @Jarlh asked a good question -- what about dates like January 1?  Is it 01Jan2019 or 1Jan2019?  If it can be either, perhaps a regex would work.

```
select
  substring (date from '\d+(\D{3}\d{4})') as month,
  count (distinct customer)
from t
group by month
```

The 'distinct customer' also presupposes you may have the same customer listed in the same month, but you only want to count it once.  If that's not the case, just remove 'distinct.'

And, if you wanted the output in date format:

```
select
  to_date (substring (date from '\d+(\D{3}\d{4})'), 'monyyyy') as month,
  count (distinct customer)
from t
group by month
```

Answer (score -1):

If it is a date column, you can truncate the date:

```
select date_trunc('month', date) as yyyymm, count(*)
from t
group by yyyymm
order by yyyymm;
```

I really read that the type was `date`.  For a string, just use string functions:

```
select substr(date, 3, 7) as mmmyyyy, count(*)
from t
group by mmmyyyy;
```

Unfortunately, ordering doesn't work in this case.  You should really be storing dates using the proper type.

Comment: op said `column is of text data type`

Comment: group by can use expressions, won't cause issue if there is a column of the same name in the future

Comment: substr will cut months for some locales (eg if 1st january 2018 is represented by 1Jan2018)

Comment: postgres `to_date(date_string, date_format)` should be preferred solution to convert that string to date in locale safe way, then formatting to just year-month can be performed to acheve value that can be grouped by

Comment: Can you use the alias in the `GROUP BY` ?

Comment: @przemo_li not locale here, op save date as strings

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . You can use the alias in the `GROUP BY` in Postgres.